# How can i resample this Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I'm trying to resample  the upcoming DF , for later making Lag Features.

```
Mi_Meteo.head()


  Sensor ID   Time Instant    Measurement
0   14121   2013/11/14 17:00    0.8
1   14121   2013/11/14 18:00    0.6
2   14121   2013/11/14 19:00    0.4
3   14121   2013/11/14 20:00    0.4
4   14121   2013/11/14 21:00    0
```

So , That's What I've Done:

```
Mi_Meteo = Mi_Meteo.set_index(['Time Instant']) # to Make The Time Instant as an Index
```

And Then :

```
Mi_Meteo.index = pd.to_datetime(Mi_Meteo.index) #  to convert it to a DateTimeIndex
```

But i Get This Error:

```
Unknown string format
```

Knowing That I want to Get A DF like This ( with a temporal range of 3H)

```
    Time Instant         Sensor ID          Measurement
0   2013/11/14 00:00:00    14121                0.8
1   2013/11/14 03:00:00    14121                0.6
2   2013/11/14 06:00:00    14121                0.4
3   2013/11/14 09:00:00    14121                0.4
4   2013/11/14 12:00:00    14121                 0
```

Thank U all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some bad data, convert them to `NaN`s by `errors='coerce'` parameter:

```
Mi_Meteo.index = pd.to_datetime(Mi_Meteo.index, errors='coerce')
```

If need check these rows:

```
print (Mi_Meteo[pd.to_datetime(Mi_Meteo.index, errors='coerce').isna()])
```

Comment: That Actually Solved my problem Thank u